# Sqlite table is not deleted

Tags: sqlite

We use Sqlite in our Java application(Driver version 3.40.1.0).
The problem is that the tables are not deleted correctly.
Let's say we have the following JDBC URL - **jdbc:sqlite:./sample.db**

1. We created the table: CREATE TABLE Lines (line VARCHAR(32))
2. We created the index: CREATE INDEX idxLines ON Lines(line)
3. Then we dropped this table: DROP TABLE Lines

Table seems to be dropped. If we try to create the same table immediately then we receive an error:

```
Caused by: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: Lines)
```

But if close Java application and start it again and try to create the table then we receive weird error:

```
Caused by: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (table Lines already exists)
```

Comment: Have you tried `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` and `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`? They are much safer.

Comment: Probably that will work but this Sqlite behavior seems to be a bug and should be fixed.
Secondly, I have to additionally truncate the table (I double that Sqlite does that).